# Crashing the PC with one thread with priority 15, and affinity to single processor

Tags: windows, multithreading, operating-system, kernel

Iv'e opened CPUSTRESS with affinity of the process to a single processor. I then set a priority of one of the threads to Time Critical, which means priority 15. Twice I have tried raising the stress on the Time Critical thread to 15, and twice my PC crashed - keyboard and mouse stopped responding, image on screen wouldn't refresh, etc.
I suspect this is caused by the single thread somehow taking the computer's resources to manage IO, etc. But the rest of the CPUs were free (I have 8 CPUs, iv'e set the affinity of the CPUSTRESS process to CPU 7).

So why would that happen?

Comment: I'm guessing that real-time priority, together with the affinity lock, is preventing the prompt processing of inter-core driver messages on core 7.  Certainly, using up 7 out of 8 cores with 'above normal priority' CPU-intensive threads, and without the affinity lock, alllows my box to be still useable, though the UI is laggy and the fan noise is annoying.  Try taking the affinity lock off.

Comment: Hey, I understand when using 7 out of 8 cores the system might be slow. What was weird to me that using only 1 out of 8 cores was enough to stop the system.